# how to use lambda function to assign values based on other columns while using 'or' for multiple values for the same outcome?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

[image]

so if col2 = a or b col3 to be assigned 'yes' else if col 2 is c col3 to be assigned 'no'

to have the below output:

[image]

I have tried using lambda but it worked only for the first condition

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map):

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].map({'a': 'yes', 'b': 'yes', 'c': 'no'})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
0     1    a  yes
1     2    b  yes
2     3    c   no
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, `isin` then `map`:

```
l = ['a','b']
df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].isin(l).map({True:'yes', False:'no'})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
0     1    a  yes
1     2    b  yes
2     3    c   no
```

Update this is not recommended for this problem, but here is the syntax I think you are looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1,2,3], 'Col2':[*'abc'], 'Col3':[np.nan]*3})
df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].apply(lambda x: 'yes' if (x == 'a') | (x == 'b') else 'no')
df
```

Output:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
0     1    a  yes
1     2    b  yes
2     3    c   no
```

Comment: thank you for the response,I am trying to use lambda as there are outputs other than yes and no and the givens in col2 are not limited to a,b and c,